# How to read an excel format that it is save as web page in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate the process of updating data for a program in R. This data is download from:
 http://obiee.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Download&Format=excel&Extension=.xls&BypassCache=true&Path=/shared/Consulta%20Series%20Estadisticas%20desde%20Excel/1.%20Tasas%20de%20Captacion/1.1%20Serie%20empalmada/1.1.2%20Semanales/1.1.2.1%20DTF,CDT%20180%20d%C3%ADas,CDT%20360%20d%C3%ADas%20y%20TCC%20-%20(Desde%20el%2012%20de%20enero%20de%201984)/Serie%20historica%20IQY&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico&SyncOperation=1

The problem is that the file is said to be saved as an .xls (when you download it it is in that format) but it is actually save in a web page format (aka HTML). I know it save in the incorrect format because when trying to read it in R I got the error "Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXM" and I tried to open it manually in excel and saved it and it showed that it was actually a web page.

The code I have is:

`library(RCurl)
library(XLConnect)
f = CFILE("exfile.xlsx", mode="wb")
curlPerform(url = urlDFT, writedata = f@ref, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
close(f)
out = readWorksheetFromFile(file = "exfile.xlsx", sheet =1, header =F)`

where `urlDTF` is url mention before. The code works totally fine when the file is in any excel format, but doesn't work with wired file.

Comment: Restart R with no packages loaded and then show the code. You are obviously assuming we know where to find all these functions (and many of us are too lazy to go out and do the google-work to find them. ) Inclusion of library calls to non-standard packages is part of a [MCVE] when asking R questions

Comment: @42- I forgot about the packages, but I already have added theme in the question.

Comment: So why not then pass it to an external program that can handle it its contents? Passing to a text editor the first two lines are: `<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">`. OpenOffice.org can handle it.